# some problem for transition triangle when hover , when move mouse out the color reback so fast

Tags: css, css-transitions

i wrote this codes

style :

```
.triangle{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:0 0 100px 300px ;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;

}
.triangle:hover{
    transition: ease .9s all;
   border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;

}
```

and html :

```
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

my problem is when i move out of div the color reback to black so fast 
anybody can help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You should move the transition declaration.

```
.triangle{
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width:0 0 100px 300px ;
   border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;

   transition: ease .9s all; /*applied both when hovering, and not hovering*/

}
.triangle:hover{
   border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
}
```

If you put a transition in the `hover` state, it will only be applied when you're hovering over it. So when you move your mouse out of the triangle, the transition is gone.

By moving it to the `.triangle` class, it's applied to both states.

Comment: 22 seconds faster. good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace transition

```
.triangle{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:0 0 100px 300px ;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
    transition: ease .9s all;

}
.triangle:hover{

   border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;

}
```